Update object property after form submission for use in a seperate function
How to update a specific proprety listed in an object?
I tried so many variations that I am not sure the code makes sense any more.
let object= {
    proprety1:'',
    ...

}

Whether these propreties are populated, a different .div will be displayed:
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        if(object.proprety1 === ""){
            document.querySelector('.first-screen-div').style.display = 'flex';
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                newObjectForm(event);
            });
        }else {
            document.querySelector('.second-screen-div').style.display = 'flex';
        }

        
    })

The form is handled in the below function:
let form = document.getElementById('object-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', newObjectForm);
function newObjectForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let objectOne = document.getElementById('object-one').value;

    object.proprety1= objectOne 

    document.getElementById('object-form').submit();

}  

I want this empty proprty to be updated after submission of a form, with the form value so I can reuse it with future functions.
here is the form:
<div class="first-screen-div">
            <form method="GET" action="" class="" id="object-form">
       
                <input type="text" id="object-one" name="object-one" placeholder="" class="" required><br><br> 
 
                <button class="" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
</div>

If I console.log() outside the function, the value entered in the form is not printed, which makes me thing the data is updating Proprety1.
I also used .push() which didnt result in better result. I am clearly doing something wrong but cannot find the root cause.
Any suggestion?

Before continuing, you need to get famililar with forms.

I think you can update it on fetch success promeses

If you submit the form, then the browser will load a new page as result of that submission. Even if you are targeting the same URL you were "on" already, with your form action - you are still loading a fresh document. And in that, all of your JS variables of course have their initial values.

@CBroe So I should just use an input instead? It makes sense now you present it like that. edit( as in, removing the form, and just working on an input value)

It seems that object should be a const not let. Everything that you do not intend to reassign should be const.
Also, I would not name it object. Name it dataContainer or something else.
object is almost Object which has special meaning in js.

If you want data to persist across reloads, save it in localStorage or sessionStorage, then retrieve it when the page loads.

Define the event listener for the submit event once and not as part of the conditional statement.


let object1 = {
  proprety1: ''
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let form = document.getElementById('object-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', newObjectForm);

  if (object1.proprety1 === "") {
    //document.querySelector('.first-screen-div').style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    //document.querySelector('.second-screen-div').style.display = 'flex';
  }
});

function newObjectForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  object1.proprety1 = event.target['object-one'].value;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: .5em;
}
<form method="GET" id="object-form">
  <input type="text" id="object-one" name="object-one" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



